# Change Default Hive result to some values

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to get duplicate record count from table, but for particular partitions data is not available, so hive is only printing "OK" result.
Is it possible to change this result with some value like 0 Or NULL.
Yes have tried with nvl,COALESCE,case option still it showing OK. AND goal is to only check duplicate count, so required at least one value

```
select col1, col2, nvl(count(*),0) AS DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME
from  xyz
where data_dt='20170423'
group by col1,col2
having count(*) >1
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Add a data sample to your post, including required results. P.s. By all means, work with date type or at least with ISO format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz There are no data: '...but for particular partitions data is not available'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return no rows on empty dataset because you are using `group by` and `having` filter. Group by having nothing to group, that is why it does not return any rows. Without group by and having query returns 0:

```
select  nvl(count(*),0) cnt, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME
from  xyz
where data_dt='20170423'
```

As a solution you can UNION ALL with null row when empty dataset

```
select col1, col2, nvl(count(*),0) AS DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME
from  xyz
where data_dt='20170423'
group by col1,col2
having count(*) >1

UNION ALL --returns 1 row on empty dataset

select col1, col2, DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, TABLE_NAME 
  from (select null col1, null col2, null AS DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME
       )a --inner join will not return rows when non-empty dataset
      inner join (
select count(*) cnt from  --should will return 0 on empty dataset
( --your original query
select col1, col2, nvl(count(*),0) AS DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME
from  xyz
where data_dt='20170423'
group by col1,col2
having count(*) >1
)s --your original query
)s on s.cnt=0
```

Also it's may be possible to use CTE (`WITH`) and `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of `inner join`for your subquery, didn't test it.

Also you can use shell to get result and test it on empty value:

```
dataset=$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; [YOUR QUERY HERE]);
# test on empty dataset

if [[ -z "$dataset" ]] ; then 
  dataset=0
fi
```

Comment: query seems correct but hive does not support dual,
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 2:5 Table not found 'dual'
shell query execution is correct but required result in hive shell only

Comment: Then create dual with single row. Or alternatively use select  without table, you can do it because there is no need in table: `select col1, col2,  DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, TABLE_NAME from (select null col1, null col2, null AS DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME)a` instead of `select null col1, null col2, null AS DUPLICATE_ROW_COUNT, 'xyz' AS TABLE_NAME
from  default.dual`

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no dual by default: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1558

Comment: You can pass shell result as a --hiveconf varible to the HQL script